# Highlight if two values of different column comes alternatively

Tags: r

it little tricky for me, so lets say i have a data frame like below

```
|ID1|ID2|T/F|
|---|---|---|
|653|385|0|
|844|610|0|
|240|970|1|
|970|240|1|
|826|551|0|
|872|854|0|
|556|460|0|
|440|490|0|
```

so we have two columns ID1 and ID2, and i want to mutate "T/F"  to 1/0
if any two values in circular references each other  for eg ID 970 report to ID 240
in next row again 240 report to 970. kind of circular referencing. if this happen in any of the row the mutate T/F to 1 else 0

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to join the dataframe with itself to find a circular match.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  inner_join(df, by = c('ID1' = 'ID2')) %>%
  right_join(df, by = c('ID1', 'ID2')) %>%
  mutate(TF = +(!is.na(ID1.y))) %>%
  select(-ID1.y)

#  ID1 ID2 TF
#1 653 385  1
#2 240 970  1
#3 970 240  1
#4 385 653  1
#5 844 610  0
#6 826 551  0
#7 872 854  0
#8 556 460  0
#9 440 490  0
```

This can be written in base R as :

```
transform(merge(merge(df, df, by.x = 'ID1', by.y = 'ID2'), 
          df, all.y = TRUE), TF = +(!is.na(ID1.y)))
```

**data**

Added an extra row in the data to include one more match.

```
df <- structure(list(ID1 = c(653, 844, 240, 970, 826, 872, 556, 440, 
385), ID2 = c(385, 610, 970, 240, 551, 854, 460, 490, 653)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
df

#  ID1 ID2
#1 653 385
#2 844 610
#3 240 970
#4 970 240
#5 826 551
#6 872 854
#7 556 460
#8 440 490
#9 385 653
```

---

**EDIT**

For the actual dataset we may need to change the column names.

```
df5 %>%
  inner_join(df5, by = c("ID 1" = "ID 2")) %>%
  right_join(df5, by = c("ID 1" , "ID 2")) %>%
  mutate(TF = +(!is.na(`ID 1.y`))) %>%
  select(-`ID 1.y`)
```

Comment: when i am using like this getting error

df5 <- structure(list(`ID 1` = c(653, 844, 240, 970, 826, 872, 556, 440, 
                             385), `ID 2` = c(385, 610, 970, 240, 551, 854, 460, 490, 653)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                        -9L), class = "data.frame")


df %>%
  inner_join(df, by = c('ID 1' = 'ID 2')) %>%
  right_join(df, by = c('ID 1', 'ID 2')) %>%
  mutate(TF = +(!is.na(`ID 1.y`))) %>%
  select(-`ID1.y`)

Comment: @user14176250 You need to change the column names according to your columns. Usually it is better not to have spaces in column names. See the edit part in the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match` to *show if any two values in circular references each other*.

```
match(x$ID1, x$ID2) == match(x$ID2, x$ID1)
#[1]   NA   NA TRUE TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Or using `interaction` with `%in%`.

```
+(interaction(x) %in% interaction(rev(x)))
#[1] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(ID1=c(653,844,240,970,826,872,556,440),
 ID2=c(385,610,970,240,551,854,460,490))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `igraph` solution

```
library(igraph)

df <- within(
  df,
  TF <- +(degree(graph_from_data_frame(df), as.character(ID1)) > 1)
)
```

which gives

```
> df
  ID1 ID2 TF
1 653 385  0
2 844 610  0
3 240 970  1
4 970 240  1
5 826 551  0
6 872 854  0
7 556 460  0
8 440 490  0
```